# .Net trouble of reference to difference version of library

Tags: c#, .net, f#

I have F#(C# I think the same) project **A** that have reference to QuickGraph library of version 3.4. **A** used in project **B** that have reference to modern QuickGraph 3.6. In app.config of **B**:

```
 <runtime>
     <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="QuickGraph" publicKeyToken="f3fb40175eec2af3" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.6.61114.0" newVersion="3.6.61114.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>    
 </runtime>
```

Its works. Anouther project **C** load in runtime **B**. When called some methods of **A** I received an IO error: cannot load version 3.4 of QuickGraph library.

Project **C** isn't my project and I can't recompile this. What I can do to avoid this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is called "Dependency Hell".

Solution from MSDN:

> If you have multiple versions of an assembly in a directory and you
>   want to reference a particular version of that assembly, you must use
>   the  element instead of the privatePath attribute of the
>    element. If you use the  element, the runtime stops
>   probing the first time it finds an assembly that matches the simple
>   assembly name referenced, whether it is a correct match or not. If it
>   is a correct match, that assembly is used. If it is not a correct
>   match, probing stops and binding fails.

Or you could use AppDomain.AssemblyResolve Event to resolve the assembly to be used.